# How to make RatingBar to show five stars

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am following the standard example of how to add a `RatingBar`. To control the number of stars I tried to use `android:numStars="5"`. The problem is that the number of stars doesn't seem to do anything at all. In portrait-layout I get 6 stars and when I flip the phone I get about 10 stars. I tried to set the number of stars in my Activity (`myBar.setNumStars(5)`) that loads the xml but there was no success with that option either.

So my question is how do I define my layout so that it will only show five stars? Set `numStars` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

```
<RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:stepSize="0.1"
            android:isIndicator="true" />
```

in code

```
mRatingBar.setRating(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was that you can't use android:layout_width="fill_parent" since the RatingBar apperenty ignores the android:numStars othervise. :-/

Comment: My requirement is setting ratingbar to fill parent or match parent but fixed stars i.e. 5. how to do it? is it possible?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar have u tried 3 different sizes in "style" attribute? e.g. ratingBarStyle

Answer (score 81):

The `RatingBar.setNumStar` documentation says:

> Sets the number of stars to show. In order for these to be shown
>   properly, it is recommended the layout width of this widget be wrap
>   content.

So setting the layout width to `wrap_content` should solve this problem.

Answer (score 29):

This worked for me: `RatingBar` should be inside `LinearLayout` other than having layout width set to wrap content for `RatingBar`.

Comment: @ValentinGalea not so strange though: rating bar minds its own width, while the external LinearLayout cares about filling its parent layout width.

Answer (score 14):

Additionally, if you set a `layout_weight`, this supersedes the `numStars` attribute.

Comment: This really should be in the docs. I found that even adding a margin right setting also throws off numStars

Comment: This was good advice. I removed the padding to finally make it work for me.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Use wrap_content and it will only show the set numStars :)

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: This one helps me.Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You should just use 
`numStars="5"` in your XML, and set 
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`.
Then, you can play around with styles and other stuff, but the "wrap_content" in layout_width is what does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

```
<RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="@style/custom_rating_bar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:numStars="5" 
                    />
```

Configure the number of Stars in the XML file... No need to provide it in Styles or Activity/Fragment ....
IMPORTANT: Make sure you Put the WIDTH as Wrap content and  weights are not enabled

Answer (score 5):

I'm also facing the problem that exceeding the stars than specified no of stars. For this, we don't want worry about whatever the layout type either relative or linear layout. Simply use the width as follows:

```
ratingBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Please **avoid** using **match_parent and fill_parent** for **ratingbar**.

Hope the things would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are wrapping the `RatingBar` inside a `ConstraintLayout` with `match_constraint` for its width, the editor preview is going to show a number of stars proportional to its actual width, no matter what if you set `android:numStars` property. Use `wrap_content` to get the correct preview:

```xml
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/myRatingBar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
           android:numStars="5"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Even i was facing the issue @Roland , I had included one more attribute called

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in my `RatingBar` declaration in XML. This attribute prevented from setting of the stars required and setting up the `NumStars`

Keep posted on the issues you come across !

Comment: Just helped a friend with the same thing. I suggested this approach, and found out later that it was invalid.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had an issue until I removed the padding.  It looks like there is a bug on certain devices that doesn't alter the size of the view to accommodate the padding, and instead compresses the contents.

Remove `padding`, use `layout_margin` instead.

Answer (score 1):

To show a simple star rating in round figure just use this code

```
public static String getIntToStar(int starCount) {
        String fillStar = "\u2605";
        String blankStar = "\u2606";
        String star = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++) {
            star = star.concat(" " + fillStar);
        }
        for (int j = (5 - starCount); j > 0; j--) {
            star = star.concat(" " + blankStar);
        }
        return star;
    }
```

And use it like this

button.setText(getIntToStar(4));

Answer (score 1):

You can add default rating of five stars in side the xml layout

```
android:rating="5"
```

Edit:

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rb_vvm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space2"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space1"
        style="@style/RatingBar"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:rating="5" />
```

Comment: Please clarify with an example on how to add this to the xml layout.

Comment: I have added the complete view.

Answer (score 0):

The default value is set with [andoid:rating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#attr_android%3arating) in the xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ruleRatingBar"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `RatingBar` stretched to a maximum number of stars because it was enclosed in a Table with the attribute `android:stretchColumns  = "*"`.

Once I took `stretchCoulumns` off all columns, the `RatingBar` displayed according to the `android:numStars` value

Answer (score 0):

### Another possibility is you are using the Rating in Adapter of list view

```
View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
```

**Below params are necessary for all the attributes to work properly:**

1. Set the **`root`** to **`parent`**
2. boolean **`attachToRoot`** as **`false`**

**Ex:**
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myId, parent, false);

Answer (score 0):

The actual thing over here is to use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`. If you will use `match_parent` the layout will be filled with the stars even if it is more than the *numStars* variable.

Comment: Could you provide some useful examples ?

Comment: yes, on match parent it was showing 8 start, but on wrap content it showed 5