# Ratings bar in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have an application that has a custom Ratings bar. The code for the same is below:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/FillWrap.LL.Footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/IV_Prev" android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
            style="@style/Wrap" android:layout_weight="0.35" />
        <RatingBar android:id="@+id/RB_Stars" style="@style/Wrap"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratings_bar" android:numStars="3"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" android:stepSize="1" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/IV_Next" android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            style="@style/Wrap" android:layout_weight="0.35" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the ratings_bar drawable is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_swipe_fav_off_default"/>
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_swipe_fav_focused" />
</layer-list>
```

I'm able to see a proper rating bar with 3 stars in the portrait mode as below:
[image]

but in the landscape mode, the same becomes like
[image]

Can some one tell me why, and how can I circumvent this problem. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

into your < RatingBar >

Comment: The `layout_width` bit is the most important. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858600/how-to-make-ratingbar-to-show-five-stars/10819710