# Problems with Android's RatingBar

Tags: android, rating

I'm trying to customize a bit the android's RatingBar.

I found a [tutorial](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/) to do that, but I have a problem.

I set property of rating bar numStars to 5.

What I get, that every 'star' of rating bar will be represented of three of mine.

I read in comments to this tutorial, that somebody's got the similar problem, but there is no solution for that problem.

Can somebody try this tutorial on Android 2.2? Or recommend another tutorial?

Thank you in advance

**UPD:**

And here is a bit of my code:

**res/drawable/star_selector_full_filled.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_highlighted" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_highlighted" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_highlighted" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_highlighted" />

</selector>
```

**res/drawable/star_selector_empty.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_white" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_white" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_window_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_white" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_white" />

</selector>
```

**res/drawable/star_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_selector_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_selector_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/star_selector_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

**res/values/styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="starRatingBar" parent="android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_selector</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">25dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">25dip</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... it has something to do with the min version you deploy to and the screen size.

I solved it manually setting the supported screen sizes in the android manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true" 
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Hope it helps.

## Edit:

I actually answered this same problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7380381/939420)

All you need to do is **set the layout width to wrap_content**

Comment: so i guess, it has more something with the screen size. But, minVersion = 8, and supports screen is in the manifest as well :(