# The Number of Stars in the RatingBar Looks Wrong

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

The number of stars in the RatingBar seems to be more than I have set. Although I set it to 5, more stars appear on the screen. The screen shots are below. However, the normal number appears when choosing the stars.

**My empty RatingBar's stars count are not coming true. Empty ratingbar is not showing, android default RatingBar is shown. When my RatingBar is filling, both of my filled RatingBar and android default RatingBar is showing.**

[image: First Photo]

[image: Second Photo]

My code is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratingInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/callRatingBar"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/topTitle" />

</LinearLayout>

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/transparent_black_30"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:theme="@style/"
    tools:rating="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/limit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|center_horizontal"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:gravity="end|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="200"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/infoTitle" />

<com.project.android.util.view.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/commentText"
    style="@style/EditTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:hint="@string/leaveAComment"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/textSendButton"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/textSendButton"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/edittext_scrollbar"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/infoTitle"
    app:emojiSize="@dimen/conversation_emojiSize" />
```

MyRatingBar style:

```
 <style name="MyRatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightTransparentBlack</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pin_yellow</item>
        <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Please share full code of your xml file

Comment: I added full code my xml file. Please help me.

Comment: Try removing colorControlNormal from the style

Comment: And also remove all the unnecessary attributes as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the amount of stars via code?

```
ratingBar.setRating(int)
```

The ratingbar is known for having weird bugs like this

[Also look at the various reasons for it not working here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858600/how-to-make-ratingbar-to-show-five-stars)

Comment: My empty RatingBar's stars count are not coming true. Empty ratingbar is not showing, android default RatingBar is shown. When my RatingBar is filling, both of my filled RatingBar and android default RatingBar is showing.